# What is wrong with this line of PHP code

Tags: php

Let's get directly to this weird confusing problem, WHAT IS WRONG WITH THIS LINE OF CODE:

```
<?php 
global $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","myshop");
?>
```

The error I get from loading this is this:

**Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting ',' or ';'**

Comment: $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","myshop"); then use it that way $GLOBALS['con'];

Comment: Thanks, that was the right answer <3

Answer (score 0):

Remove the global keyword. If you need to pass the database parameter to a function,  rather pass as arguments in the function. The global keyword use is bad practice .

Alternatively,  you can put the database connection in a file and include it where you need it.  Doing so,  you'll only need to use the same variable $con. Do not use global keyword

Answer (score 0):

You can reach your global variables this way:

```
<?php 
  $GLOBALS['con'] = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","myshop");
  function a_function($query){
     mysqli_query($GLOBALS['con'],$query);
  }
?>
```

This is not the best practice to store your database link, but in your case, this is the solution.

Please take care with SQL Injection leaks also!

Comment: Then it says: syntax error, unexpected ';' on line 4 LOL

Comment: This is only an example how to use GLOBAL variables as mysql connection  :) I made a mistake, I've corrected it, check it again, but you have to work on your furter code

Comment: @ciomaejobaep: If it worked please accept my answer, thx..